# Aadhaar integration with Android app

Tags: android

I am looking for Aadhaar integration with my Android app

I have found a sample to test link https://developer.uidai.gov.in/book/export/html/18 and https://developer.uidai.gov.in/node/22 but it's provided for java web based platform.

If the same can be used means how can be achieved to integrate with android app or else any API or SDK is there means please guide me to proceed

Comment: try this http://bridge.aadhaarconnect.com/ may its help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Samsung India Identity SDK for **Aadhaar Iris** integration.
For getting SDK from Samsung you have to enroll to their portal and get Sample demo and SDK.

#### [Samsung India SEAP portal](https://seap.samsung.com/enrollment)

---

### Note

**You can use SDK only with  Samsung IRIS tablet**